# i want to jQuery ui dialog's width to be adjusted according to content, But auto-width feature wont work in IE9 ,

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

1.this the code to show jQuery dialog

```
function onSucess(result) {
        result = result.substring(result.indexOf("<"), result.length);
        $("#div1").html(result);
        $('#div1').dialog({
            modal: true,
            height: 'auto',
            width:'auto',
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
 }
```

as you can see, both height and width are set to auto mode

Answer (score 0):

try `width:"100%"` instead of `width:"auto"`. similarly height too.